# Xcode horizontal iPad frame issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit

I have a problem with Xcode, I am trying to make a SpriteKit game. This project is for iPad and is strictly horizontal. My problem lies with the frame. It seems some of my view is being cut off. I NSlogged the position of every touch co-ordinate. When I click in the bottom left (should be x:0,y:0 right?) I get x:0,y:300

It seems some of my view is being cut off, please help how do I solve this problem so that the view fits the horizontal iPad view.

Thanks

Comment: I can't find anything on this problem :/

Comment: @JoshuaTruscott please show the code which adds the scene to `SKView`. It's always better to paste the code then trying to describe what should it do

Comment: @AndreyGordeev : woops, did not know about that :] I'll remove my comments to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your project for a .sks file, make sure the dimensions are correct. E.g. 1024x768 for landscape iPad.